# Form1_load code not working when starting the program

Tags: vb.net

I have written all mode code out correctly but when the program runs it does work in the program! I do not know the issue here and was hoping an expert here on VB.net could help out as I have only taken one class of programming in my life...

It is a tic tac toe game for anyone wondering.

I have tried everything I've seen on here and other websites.

Also, the point of the code is so when someone wins it is supposed to display a message box saying they won and then add 1 to the text box in the top left or right.

Here is some code from the form_load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Generate Random Start
    If TurnResult = 1 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = "Red Player's Turn"
    End If
    If TurnResult = 2 Then
        lblPlayerTurn.Text = "Blue Player's Turn"
    End If

    'Blue Winners
    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Blue Player Wins!")
        txtBlue.Text += 1
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn2.Text = "X" And btn3.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Blue Player Wins!")
        txtBlue.Text += 1
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If btn4.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn6.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Blue Player Wins!")
        txtBlue.Text += 1
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If btn7.Text = "X" And btn8.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Blue Player Wins!")
        txtBlue.Text += 1
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If btn1.Text = "X" And btn4.Text = "X" And btn7.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Blue Player Wins!")
        txtBlue.Text += 1
        btn1.Enabled = False
        btn2.Enabled = False
        btn3.Enabled = False
        btn4.Enabled = False
        btn5.Enabled = False
        btn6.Enabled = False
        btn7.Enabled = False
        btn8.Enabled = False
        btn9.Enabled = False
    End If
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit on the description of your problem. What exactly it is that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: All your eveluations (Blue only?) are in `Form.Load`. This code will be executed when the Form is first loaded and only then. Unless you have pasted here semi-random pieces of code.

Comment: So this part of the code is supposed to display the winner in a msgbox and then add a win to the text box on the form. But when i start the program it doesn't display a winner when they get 3 in a row, like a normal tic tac toe game.

Comment: How can there be a winner known in form load?  The user has not even seen the form yet

Comment: As @Jimi indicated, the code in your question will only be executed once your `Form1` is loaded for the first time; that's it. So, unless "they get 3 in a row" _**before**_ the form is loaded (somehow), no winner will be displayed. You probably want to move that code to the event handler that changes the text of the buttons.